# Apache Solr Filter on Child Documents

Tags: solr, lucene, solrcloud

I have a Document that also contains the list of child documents in it like this:-

```
{

    "pf1":"data1",
    "pf2":"data2",
    "path":"1.parent",
    "_childDocuments":[
        {
            "cf1":"data101",
            "cf2":"data102",
            "path":"2.child"
        },
        {
            "cf1":"data111",
            "cf2":"data112",
            "path":"2.child"
        }
    ]

}
```

I want to query on child document where `cf1` has value `data101`. that means my output will be something like this.

```
{

    "pf1":"data1",
    "pf2":"data2",
    "path":"1.parent",
    "_childDocuments":[
        {
            "cf1":"data101",
            "cf2":"data102",
            "path":"2.child"
        }
    ]

}
```

I am not able to generate the query for this.
Is there any way I can query on child document and also get those childs which contain my result ?

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could do that with the help of [ChildDocTransformer](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/transforming-result-documents.html#TransformingResultDocuments-_child_-ChildDocTransformerFactory)

You should have normal query on the parent documents, as you're doing now, for example:

```
q=pf1:data1
```

and apply transformer in the field list parameter:

```
fl=pf1,pf2,path,[child parentFilter=type:parent childFilter=cf1:data101]
```

You need to choose parentFilter carefully, since the query that you will use there, should only match parent docs. So, in my example `type:parent` is just a placeholder for you, and you should come up with the query, according to your data (may be you should even add some field type for easier distinction)